# Proving that $\int_0^\infty \frac{(x/y)^a}{x+y}dy$ doesn't depend on x

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to show that for any fixed $a\in (0,1)$, the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{(x/y)^a}{x+y}dy = c$ for every $x>0$ (so, if say $f(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{(x/y)^a}{x+y}dy$, $x>0$, then I claim that f is constant).

I was trying to compute the integral explicitly and later to just calculate the derivative with respect to x (showing it is 0 would prove f is constant), but without success.
If I didn't make a mistake, then $f^{'}(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{(a-1)x^a+ax^{a-1}y}{y^a(x+y)^2}dy$, but I don't think showing that it is zero for every x is any simpler than the task we started with.

Comment: What's wrong with using change-of-variables, setting $y=xt$, for instance?

Comment: Now generally, $\int_0^\infty f(y/x)dy/x$ is the same for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I just missed the simplest substitution...

As @J.G. mentioned, generally $\int_0^\infty f(y/x)dy/x$ is the same for all $x>0$: we just substitute $y=xt$, and get (at least assuming f is integrable)
$$\int_0^\infty f(y/x)dy/x = \int_0^\infty f(t)dt$$
In my case we have just $f(y/x) = \frac{(y/x)^{-a}}{1+y/x}$.

Comment: For what it's worth, this integral is $\pi\csc\pi a$.